# How can one see whether the silent mode is activated without using hardware?

Tags: iphone, sound-volume

One can switch the silent mode on and off on an iPhone as follows:

[image]

How can one see whether the silent mode is activated without using hardware? (i.e., just looking at the screen, without using the side buttons)

Answer (score 2):

The Assistive Touch menu, under Device, contains Mute or Unmute depending on the state of the physical switch, providing the menu is not used to override the switch.

[image: Screenshot of Assistive Touch menu]

Comment: just weird that the crossed out bell means that the sound is on